# ¿Como puedo enumerar registros por año?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buenos días compañeros,

Les comento estoy generando un reporte (Procedimiento) el cual contiene todos los datos con un campo de fecha tipo datetime (Fecha Creacion), mi pregunta es como puedo generar el query para enumerar los registros por año es decir me enumere los registros que existe por 2018,2019, 2020, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo construido es lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @PROCESO_CONTROL_CONTRATOS AS INT

SET @PROCESO_CONTROL_CONTRATOS = CAST(ISNULL((SELECT P.Valor
                                      FROM Parametros P
                                      WHERE P.Nombre = 'PROCESO_CONTROL_CONTRATOS'),'0') AS INT)

SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.SYSCREATED ASC) AS Consecutivo
,A.RelatedRequestID ANTERIOR
,AA.TYPE TIPO_ANTERIOR
,AA.HID HID_ANTERIOR
,A.HID HID_ACTUAL
,AT.Description DESCRIPCION_ANTERIOR
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.SYSCREATED, 103) AS FECHA_CREACION
,A.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPCION
,H.FULLNAME SOLICITANTE
,HR.fullname SUPERVISOR
,CS.FREETEXTFIELD_16 AREA
,C.CMP_NAME PROVEEDOR
,A.FREETEXTFIELD_01 TIPO_CONTRATO
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.STARTDATE, 103) FECHA_INICIO
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.ENDDATE, 103) FECHA_FIN
,ISNULL(A.FREETEXTFIELD_02,'NO') CONTRATO_FIRMADO
,ISNULL(CAST(B.HID AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'DOCUMENTO NO CARGADO') ID_DOCUMENTO
 
FROM ABSENCES A
LEFT JOIN Absences AA ON (A.RelatedRequestID = AA.ID)
LEFT JOIN AbsenceTypes AT ON (AA.Type = AT.ID)
LEFT JOIN HUMRES H ON (A.EMPID = H.RES_ID) 
LEFT JOIN HUMRES HR ON (A.FREEINTFIELD_01 = HR.RES_ID) 
LEFT JOIN CICMPY C ON (C.CMP_WWN = A.CUSTOMERID)
LEFT JOIN BACODISCUSSIONS B ON (B.ID = A.DOCUMENTID) 
INNER JOIN CSCOLFREEABSENCES CS ON (A.ID = CS.LINKID)
WHERE A.TYPE = @PROCESO_CONTROL_CONTRATOS
AND AA.TYPE IN (775,776)
```

Muchas gracias y quedo atento a sus comentarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que te falta es particionar el número consecutivo que ya tienes calculado:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR,A.SYSCREATED) ORDER BY A.SYSCREATED ASC) AS Consecutivo
```

Esto debiera seguir generando un número de fila, pero el contador se reiniciará con cada cambio de año.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono sin ningun inconveniente.